# SurfaceView мелькает черным?

Tags: android, java

При загрузке фрагмента через navigation drawer мелькает черный экран на SurfaceView. Искал решение, нашел на [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772862/surfaceview-flashes-black-on-load). Но, к сожалению, не могу разобраться, что именно там надо сделать. Объясните, пожалуйста! Не сплю ночами!

Пробовал добавлять пустой SurfaceView на главный layout, но, к сожалению, результатов это не дало...

Comment: @BaJIuK, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем. Вы можете опубликовать ответ в виде ответа (а не обновления вопроса).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделал все фрагменты на активити, и все работает!

UPD: [решение](http://toster.ru/q/149133)

Answer (score 0):

Так там же ясно написали

> As crazy as this answer sounds, adding a 0px * 0px SurfaceView in the layout of your activity (the activity of the root layout), actually removes the black Flashing of the SurfaceView in your fragment! I did this and it works perfectly!

то есть добавление SurfaceView с нулевыми размерами в лайаут активити решает проблему с SurfaceView в фрагментах этой активити.

Comment: Я так делал, но это не дало никаких результатов. SurfaceView все равно мигал черным при загрузке... Куда я только этот пустой 0px * 0px SurfaceView не добавлял, все равно мигало. Сейчас переделал все фрагменты на активити, и все работает!